# program displays nothing when run

Tags: java, swing

I copied a tutorial program and made some modifications and now when i run it nothing happens.

I type java Teqscene into command prompt, it waits a few seconds and the shows the line for entering a new command. The program compiles fine and im new to swing so im not sure what iv missed ? can anyoun tell wht this program does not work ?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class Teqscene implements ActionListener, ChangeListener
{
    JFrame appFrame;
    JLabel[] captions = new JLabel[24];
    JLabel curScene;
    JSlider[] sliders = new JSlider[16];
    JButton scene1, scene2, scene3, scene4, save, load, connect, address, write;    
    GridBagConstraints[] gridBagConstraints = new GridBagConstraints[60];
    Container cPane;
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        new Teqscene();
    }
    public void Teqscene() 
    {
        createGUI();
    }
    public void createGUI()
    {
        /*Create a frame, get its contentpane and set layout*/
        appFrame = new JFrame("Scene setter");
        cPane = appFrame.getContentPane();
        cPane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        //Arrange components on contentPane and set Action Listeners to each JButton
        arrangeComponents();
        appFrame.pack();
        appFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
    public void arrangeComponents() 
    {
        for(int i = 0; i<24; i++)
        {
            captions[i] = new JLabel("100%");
        }
        for(int i = 0; i<24; i++)
        {
            sliders[i] = new JSlider(JSlider.VERTICAL, 0, 15, 15);
            sliders[i].addChangeListener(this);
            sliders[i].setMajorTickSpacing(1);
            sliders[i].setPaintTicks(true);
        }

        scene1 = new JButton("Scene 1");
        scene2 = new JButton("Scene 2");
        scene3 = new JButton("Scene 3");
        scene4 = new JButton("Scene 4");
        save = new JButton("Save Scene");
        load = new JButton("Load data");
        connect = new JButton("Connect to LCU");
        address = new JButton("Set LCU IP address");
        write = new JButton("Write to LCU");

        scene1.addActionListener(this);
        scene2.addActionListener(this);
        scene3.addActionListener(this);
        scene4.addActionListener(this);
        save.addActionListener(this);       
        load.addActionListener(this);
        connect.addActionListener(this);
        address.addActionListener(this);
        write.addActionListener(this);      

        /*add all initialized components to the container*/
        gridBagConstraints[0] = new GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints[0].gridx = 0;
        gridBagConstraints[0].gridy = 0;
        gridBagConstraints[0].insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        cPane.add(scene1, gridBagConstraints[0]);

        gridBagConstraints[1] = new GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints[1].gridx = 1;
        gridBagConstraints[1].gridy = 0;
        gridBagConstraints[1].insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        cPane.add(scene2, gridBagConstraints[1]);

        gridBagConstraints[2] = new GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints[2].gridx = 2;
        gridBagConstraints[2].gridy = 0;
        gridBagConstraints[2].insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        cPane.add(scene3, gridBagConstraints[2]);

        gridBagConstraints[3] = new GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints[3].gridx = 3;
        gridBagConstraints[3].gridy = 0;
        gridBagConstraints[3].insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        cPane.add(scene4, gridBagConstraints[3]);

        gridBagConstraints[4] = new GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints[4].gridx = 4;
        gridBagConstraints[4].gridy = 0;
        gridBagConstraints[4].insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        cPane.add(curScene, gridBagConstraints[4]);

        for(int i=5; i<17; i++)
        {
            gridBagConstraints[i] = new GridBagConstraints();
            gridBagConstraints[i].gridx = i-5;
            gridBagConstraints[i].gridy = 1;
            gridBagConstraints[i].insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
            cPane.add(sliders[i-5], gridBagConstraints[i]);         
        }

        for(int i=17; i<29; i++)
        {
            gridBagConstraints[i] = new GridBagConstraints();
            gridBagConstraints[i].gridx = i-17;
            gridBagConstraints[i].gridy = 2;
            gridBagConstraints[i].insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
            cPane.add(captions[i-17], gridBagConstraints[i]);           
        }

        for(int i=29; i<41; i++)
        {
            gridBagConstraints[i] = new GridBagConstraints();
            gridBagConstraints[i].gridx = i-29;
            gridBagConstraints[i].gridy = 3;
            gridBagConstraints[i].insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
            cPane.add(sliders[i-29], gridBagConstraints[i]);            
        }

        for(int i=41; i<53; i++)
        {
            gridBagConstraints[i] = new GridBagConstraints();
            gridBagConstraints[i].gridx = i-41;
            gridBagConstraints[i].gridy = 4;
            gridBagConstraints[i].insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
            cPane.add(captions[i-41], gridBagConstraints[i]);           
        }

        gridBagConstraints[53] = new GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints[53].gridx = 0;
        gridBagConstraints[53].gridy = 5;
        gridBagConstraints[53].insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        cPane.add(save, gridBagConstraints[53]);

        gridBagConstraints[54] = new GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints[54].gridx = 1;
        gridBagConstraints[54].gridy = 5;
        gridBagConstraints[54].insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        cPane.add(load, gridBagConstraints[54]);

        gridBagConstraints[55] = new GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints[55].gridx = 2;
        gridBagConstraints[55].gridy = 5;
        gridBagConstraints[55].insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        cPane.add(connect, gridBagConstraints[55]);

        gridBagConstraints[56] = new GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints[56].gridx = 3;
        gridBagConstraints[56].gridy = 5;
        gridBagConstraints[56].insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        cPane.add(address, gridBagConstraints[56]);

        gridBagConstraints[57] = new GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints[57].gridx = 4;
        gridBagConstraints[57].gridy = 5;
        gridBagConstraints[57].insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        cPane.add(write, gridBagConstraints[57]);       
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if (e.getSource() == save) {
            save();
        } else if (e.getSource() == load) {
            load();
        } else if (e.getSource() == connect) {
            connect();
        } else if (e.getSource() == address) {
            address();
        } else if (e.getSource() == write) {
            write();
        }
    }
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i<24; i++)
        {
            if(e.getSource() == sliders[i])
            {
                //sliders[i].setValue(e.getValue);
            }
        }
    }
    void save()
    {

    }
    void load()
    {

    }
    void connect()
    {

    }
    void address()
    {

    }
    void write()
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public void Teqscene() 
{
    createGUI();
}
```

Change this to

```
public Teqscene() 
{
    createGUI();
}
```

Here the problem is inside the main method only an object is created. When creating the object constructor is called. In your program only the default constructor exits.

Answer (score 3):

I am guessing the "void" function you have is meant to be a constructor. Make sure you dont specify a return type in your constructors.

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    new Teqscene();
}
public void Teqscene() //no return type for a constructor.
{
    createGUI();
}
```

Or you can call the function (if it was meant to be a function, even though i would not recommend naming it this way as it is confusing) in the main method:

```
 new Teqscene().Teqscene();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public void Teqscene()
```

should be replace by

```
public Teqscene()
```

Otherwise the default constructor is generated by java automatically and your method won't be called.